# Moving Canvas Context From Window to Widget in Kivy's RelativeLayout in Python, Alone (No .kv Files)

Tags: python, kivy

I've got the following code snippet that will draw a board. I've read about `RelativeLayout` and seen tutorials for manipulating the .kv file, but no explanation on how to relativize the coordinates to the widget with just Python code.

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy import graphics
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

class Chessboard(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chessboard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(pos=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.bind(size=self.drawBoardandPieces)
        self.drawBoardandPieces()

    def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
        with self.canvas:
            # Reset the canvas in case of redraws.
            self.canvas.clear()
            # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares.
            edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
            for column in range(0, 8):
                for row in range(0, 8):
                    if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                        graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                        self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                    else:
                        graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                        self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(column*edge_len, row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.pos)


class SCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        app_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        app_layout.add_widget(widget=Chessboard())
        play_again_btn = Button(text="Play Again", size_hint=(1, 1))
        app_layout.add_widget(widget=play_again_btn)
        return app_layout

SCApp().run()
```

Instead of what this code renders, I need the board drawn on the canvas to appear above the button in its own `BoxLayout` container.

Also, will click event need to be contained in the `RelativeLayout` container, as well, to work only in the context of the board?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html) specifies:

> Kivy drawing instructions are not automatically relative to the
> widgets position or size.

So you must also handle the position of your chessboard. You can handle the position using something like:

```
def drawBoardandPieces(self, *args):
    with self.canvas:
        # Reset the canvas in case of redraws.
        self.canvas.clear()
        # Define the lengths of the edges of the squares.
        edge_len = min(self.height, self.width) // 8
        for column in range(0, 8):
            for row in range(0, 8):
                if ((row + column) % 2) == 0:
                    graphics.Color(0, 0, 1)
                    self.dark_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(self.width/2 - 4*edge_len + column*edge_len, self.y + row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
                else:
                    graphics.Color(1, 1, 1)
                    self.light_rect = graphics.Rectangle(pos=(self.width/2 - 4*edge_len + column*edge_len, self.y + row*edge_len), size=(edge_len, edge_len))
```

This uses `self.y` as the bottom of the chess board and calculates the `x` based on the `width` of the `Widget` and the `edge_len`. Probably should also add `self.x` to the `x` position, but that is zero in your case.

In general, your `on_touch_down()` method should check if the touch is on your `Widget` as stated in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.on_touch_down). If you determine that no other `Widgets` need to know about that `touch`, your `on_touch_down()` method can return `True`, otherwise it should return `False`.

Comment: I'm actually looking at [this documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html), where the `RelativeLayout` can somehow be applied in-code to the widget, and the use of `to_widget()` to translate window coordinates to widget coordinates.

Comment: Have a look at the code I provided in my own answer. It offer a much simpler solution over complicating the mathematics of each method in the widget with coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here's the corrected code in the app. All you need to do is to place the widget into its own `RelativeLayout`. Then, the `RelativeLayout` widget can, itself, be placed inside of a box in `BoxLayout`, a grid position in `GridLayout`, etc.

```
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

# All of that other code.

class SCApp(App):
    def build(self):
        app_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        chessboard_layout = RelativeLayout()
        chessboard_layout.add_widget(widget=Chessboard())
        app_layout.add_widget(widget=chessboard_layout))
        play_again_btn = Button(text="Play Again", size_hint=(1, 1))
        app_layout.add_widget(widget=play_again_btn)
        return app_layout
```